# Does black have an advantage if white plays 1. h4

Tags: opening

White would playing as if they are black, but with the insertion of h4. Does this insertion give enough advantage to white to at least equalize? Does the insertion of h4 weaken white's position even more than if white skipped his first move.

Comment: Isn't this just a complicated way of asking "how good is `1.h4`"? In which case the answer, based at least on historical performance and current theory, seems to be "not very good!"

Comment: It depends on against whom you are playing

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a variation that there is white's Bg5 or Ng5 which should be met h6. I mean theoretical lines. And then play with black as you were white. I think that `1. h4` makes white worse than black usually is.

- White has difficulties with castling short
- g4 instantly weak